# “Site” vs. “website”

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

I’ve always used the “website” word in referring to websites. However, [several](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/site) [dictionaries](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/site) (including [the Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/site)) mention that one of “site’s” definition is actually “a website”:

> Definition of *site* in English:
>
> 2. A website: 
>      *‘the site has no ads and is not being promoted with banners’*

Also, The New York Times name their website map [as “Site Map”](http://spiderbites.nytimes.com/), and The Guardian has news articles [with the “site” word in the title](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/jan/06/anonymous-hacks-thai-police-sites-over-burmese-jailings-for-british-backpacker-murders).

Which is the proper and the more common way of referring to websites today?

Comment: Eat dozen madder.

Comment: I think “site map” is a separate term, there’s no such thing as a “website map”.

Comment: @iamakulov "Web site" is another possibility... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Web+site%2Cwebsite%2CWebsite&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWeb%20site%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwebsite%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWebsite%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both ways are in full use.  I'd venture to say you'd find many use both and use them interchangeably.  I know I do.  Perhaps people might sometimes steer towards *website* when concerned about the ambiguity that *site* can create in a given context.  For example, I might say, "I visited Amazon's *site*," but say, "I visited Barnes & Noble's *website*," because Amazon is only known as being Internet-based, whereas Barnes & Noble is also known for having brick-and-mortar stores, so saying I visited their site could mislead the hearer to think I had visited a physical location rather than an electronic one.  Aside from that scenario, I don't see any rhyme or reason to how people choose to use *site* or *website*.  Maybe we'll see *website* slide away over time as the abbreviated *site* takes firmer hold.  Maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

**Site** is defined as:

> 1. an area of ground on which a town, building, or monument is constructed.
>         *"the proposed site of a hydroelectric dam"*
>      synonyms: plot, lot, areal; plot  "a building site"
> 2. a website.
>      "the site has no ads and is not being promoted with banners"

The first meaning can be interpreted as 'an area on the internet', meaning a webpage. That's why *site map* will point to individual pages usually.
**Website** however could represent a collection of webpages, and is also  interchangeable with **site**.

**Site** can also be considered short for *web site*, which in itself, is rarely used ([once for every 1000 times **website** is used](http://grammarist.com/spelling/web-site-website/)) nowadays. Hence **website** is more common and probably more appropriate.

Comment: The 1:1000 ratio is mentioned for “Web site vs. website”, not for “Site vs. website”.

Comment: Yes, I have said that only. I've given an example where site may be short for web site.

Comment: Ah, yep, misread that.